# Is there a power amplifier class called "bridged"?

Tags: audio, components, power-amplifier

I wanted to know what clas of amplifer the [TDA7266](https://www.st.com/en/audio-ics/tda7266.html#documentation) from STmicroelectronic is, but I couldn't understand. Its datasheet says:

> The [TDA7266](https://www.st.com/en/audio-ics/tda7266.html#documentation) is a dual bridge amplifier specially designed for TV and portable radio applications.

What does "bridge" mean in this phrase?

Comment: Think H-bridge compared with a half-bridge. You get twice the output voltage at the cost of two more transistors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From TDA7266 [datasheet](https://www.st.com/en/audio-ics/tda7266.html):

[image]

"Bridged" means each loudspeaker is driven by two amplifiers instead of one. One amp outputs a positive polarity signal (labeled "OUT+") and the other amp inverts the signal (labeled "OUT-").

This has some advantages:

It can output an AC signal of positive and negative polarity, using only one positive supply. This is quite useful for car audio, or other applications where you don't have a negative voltage avaibale, for example if it is powered by the ubiquitous 19VDC laptop brick. In the case of your TV, a bridged amp saves money on the power supply, by only requiring a positive voltage.

It doubles the output voltage swing. If each amp is capable of 0V...12V, then the voltage across the loudspeaker will be -12V...+12V, or a 24V swing. Thus, you get double the voltage swing over a more "oldskool" arrangement with a single amp and a huge DC blocking cap in the output. If the loudspeaker impedance remains the same, since P=RI^2, double the voltage means four times the power.

It also has some drawbacks:

First, obviously, you need two amps per speaker instead of one.

And, of course, doubling the voltage swing means it doubles the maximum current. So you don't get that extra power for free, the amps must be able to  provide that current.

Note that "bridged" is not a class. The bridged amplifiers themselves can be class A,B,D, whatever. These days they tend to be class D for efficiency and cost.

Comment: TY,Perfect, 1.You've told it need two amps and is harder to achive, but you mean harder to achive for semiconductor desiners, doesn't it? 2. Solved, it's class AB, it's not in datasheet but in their site! 3. what is oldskool, meaning "old-fashioned"?

Comment: The big DC blocking cap at the output of the amp is definitely old-fashioned, like 1970's era. Yes bridged needs 2 amps, so if you build discrete amps, you need 2x the parts, but when the amps are integrated on a chip, it costs much less money and complexity.

Comment: It's only "old-fashioned" if you are stuck with a single supply and a single power supply voltage. Then it's pretty much the only way make it work. And yes, getting to the point where amps are small and cheap does change the game somewhat. You also see this effect in automobile wiring. With a single, central controp processor, modern cars with electric window and locks and sensors and ... need a LOT of wiring. Expensive, complex harnesses. Stick a CANBus module and a driver on each motor and the whole thing gets much simpler. As long as the modules are cheap.

Answer (score 2):

It means the speaker is driven in a H bridge.

So both speaker terminals, positive and negative, have a signal.